# How can I sanitize the standard input in python to fixes the sonarqube issue

Tags: python, security, sonarqube, pylint

```
x = input("Enter name")

if x.lower() == "keshav":
    print(x)
```

When I run sonarqube on this code then I am getting security Hotspots issue.

You can check more related to this issue https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-4829

anyone have any idea how to fix this security issue of sonarqube

I have tried using cgi.escape(),bleach.clean() and some more thing but didn't resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, do note that in the link you provide *that rule is deprecated*:

> This rule is deprecated, and will eventually be removed.

Second, I'm mpt sure there's a way to shut up sonarqube (which is probably why the rule's getting removed, but I don't really know the tool), it's really more of a warning sign telling you to be careful but there's no way for the checker to tell you what, specifically, the issue would be, because it's completely context-dependent: the risk depends on the way you're using the value.

For instance here since you're echoing the input it *could* trigger issues if the output is meta-interpreted, the input could contain [control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) which'd affect the shell it's run in, or if the output is piped to some other software that might also be a vulnerability. However since you're checking against a single hard-coded value that can't actually happen.

So the only possible issue I can see is that the input is too large to be accessed. Since this is a Python program, it *should*<sup>[0]</sup> not trigger a buffer overflow but it could crash the program, or force the box to start swapping (depending on the configuration), leading to a denial of service condition.

Anyway you could always try applying some sort of no-op regex on the input, but... seems dumb to me, you're basically getting trained to work around the tool's stupid warning.

<sup>[0]</sup> I guess the Python runtime could have its own vulnerability there but let's assume that's not the case